# Memgraph C# Connection Issue (Session NullReferenceException) using Neo4j.Driver

Tags: c#, memgraphdb, bolt

I need to connect to my memgraph server (runs through docker), but any basic example I try ends up with a null reference exception when running any query.

The code I am using is:

```
public async void DatabaseConnectionTest()
    {
        IDriver driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://127.0.0.1:7687", AuthTokens.None);
        IAsyncSession session = driver.AsyncSession();
        try
        {
            IResultCursor cursor = await session.RunAsync("CREATE (n: TestNode) RETURN n");
            await cursor.ConsumeAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception {e.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            await session.CloseAsync();
        }

        await driver.DisposeAsync();
    }
```

When trying to run this code, I get a "NullReferenceException" to this line:

```
IResultCursor cursor = await session.RunAsync("CREATE (n: TestNode) RETURN n");
```

Am I doing something completely wrong? What am I missing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem I was facing was due to wrong configuration file for my memgraph docker container.

In the documentation of Memgraph ([as seen here](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/connect-to-memgraph/drivers/c-sharp)) it explicitly declares that to use the Neo4J.Driver in you need to apply the following changes.

> In order for the Neo4j driver to work, you need modify configuration setting --bolt-server-name-for-init. When running Memgraph, set --bolt-server-name-for-init=Neo4j/5.2.0. If you use other version of Neo4j driver, make sure to put the appropriate version number.

Now it works perfectly!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

As written [here](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/connect-to-memgraph/drivers/c-sharp#prerequisites) is necessary to add `--bolt-server-name-for-init=Neo4j/5.7.0` using the correct version of the Neo4j.Driver version.

In case you are starting memgraph using docker, use the following command:

```
docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 -v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph -e MEMGRAPH="--bolt-server-name-for-init=Neo4j/5.7.0" memgraph/memgraph-platform
```